# crontab doesnt work in linux

Tags: linux, cron, sh

**My Linux version is red hat enterprise linux server release 5.3 tikanga**

i have schedule crontab as below

```
1 * * * * /usr/testjob.sh  2>&1 >> /usr/result.txt
```

crontab job not running on scheduled time...

Please suggest..

Comment: To schedule a command at a specific time (and not periodically), take a look at the `at` command. To run every minute, use "`* * * * *`".

Comment: The order of redirections is wrong, please use `>> /usr/result.txt 2>&1`

Comment: In which crontab file did you put that line? Using what commands?

Comment: @A.H. i m using command : cronntab -e

Comment: So as long as the script file is executable and the user has the permissions to write to `/usr/result.txt` it should work.

Comment: @A.H. command used in sh file is working fine if i run manually.also i logged in as admin user.

Comment: The stuff _in_ the script is of no interest here. The script _itself_ is important. Please put some "echo Hello" right after the `#!/bin/bsh` line, put the output to `/tmp/result.txt` and check if something gets written. After _that_ is solved, you can take care of the real job - the contents of your script. Oh - did you check the logfiles of crond for some error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at first.

```
* * * * * /usr/testjob.sh
```

Then you may received a mail for every minutes.  Check the error output.
Sometimes, it may caused by your default shell is just sh instead of bash.

So, maybe ">>" is not supported.

You should check do you have /usr permission when you want to write into it.

Answer (score 1):

As said by +Shawn Chin, if you want to run your command only once, the at command is your friend.

If you want to run your command repeatedly, then you are right to use the cron framework. The manual page explaining the fields of the crontab may be obtained with the following command:

```
$ man -s 5 crontab
```

You appear to be in an Indian time-zone (IST). You may have to specify that into the crontab. For instance, using the 'crontab -e' command (to save and quit, type 'ESC-wq', as the editor is VI by default):

```
#
CRON_TZ=IST
# run at 06:33 (am), every day
33 06 * * *       /usr/testjob.sh  >> /usr/result.txt 2>&1
```

**Note that '2>&1' should be placed AFTER '>> /usr/result.txt', not before.**

Comment: Very nice and welcome aboard. One other point for new users of crontab, the nmemonic (sp?) device I use to remember the correct order (as your example shows), is that starting at the left, and moving right, you are using larger values of time in each of the first 4 columns, min, hr, day-of-mon, mon, with 5 col the days-of-week as number, consult your man page for is Sun=0 or 7? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

just to mention it and make sure

> NOTE: Each cron table entry must have a trailing line break in order
>   for the cron table entry to be recognized.